# Qt GUI in designer or in code?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When it comes to designing a GUI in Qt, I am hesitating between using the designer in Qt Creator, or doing everything in source code. I'm using Qt widgets and not QML.

If I use the designer I can easily create a GUI using qt standard widgets. But as soon as I need to subclass a widget to extend its functionality I have to build a Designer plugin to support my new widget. Is that correct? Or is there another way to it?

Comment: you have a good problematic `But as soon as I need to sub class a widget to extend it functinality I have to build a Designer plugin to support my new widget`. Then you ruin it with a question which may lead your question to be closed.

Comment: @UmNyobe I've tried to address this with my edit. There seems to be a fair question here and the answers are good. Hopefully this suffices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build all the GUI in Designer including custom widgets, and you can also build your custom widgets in Designer.

Designer does not need to interpret your custom widgets. Just use the **promote** functionality. With promote, you start with a plain widget within Designer and then tell the "real" class of it (your custom one) and the header file where it is decleared. The only drawback is that within Designer, it will stay looking like an empty widget.

In my experience, it is much better to use Designer for the GUI than writing source code yourself. You can easily change all the properties afterwards etc., and it is helpful even if you rely on custom widgets. Source code is not a good declarative language for GUI objects, with all the properties etc. Also you cannot play around, you would need to compile all the time just to tell "Is it better to have this text label in bold font?".

Sometimes I edit the XML files that are created by Designer by hand. For example, if I want to put a widget somewhere else in the object tree. If you don't mess up the XML, Designer will still read it and not destroy your changes. The only reason I see for writing GUI in source code is when you have repetitive elements, or dynamic changes based on data input, e.g. a for()-loop that produces elements. In my project I have some Selector Boxes that are filled with options in the source code.

And btw: If you prefer to write your GUI in code instead of using Designer, maybe you are not the right person to craft the GUI. Most programmers don't understand that while they are technically able to design a GUI, they are not always also competent in doing it.

http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/index.php?file=shame.htm&mode=original

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit of a shortcut, but I often use a simple QWidget as a container for my custom widget. This way, I can setup sizing policies, put the whole thing in the layout I want before my custom widget is even in. Then, in C++, I add the custom widget as a child of the container widget.

edit: As ypnos mentioned you can promote the placeholder directly. You can [find guidelines here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)

Comment: Sounds o.k., but why not use the Promote functionality in the first place? Same outcome and less complicated.